# Использование специальных символов в sqlite3

Tags: sqlite3, sqlite

Доброго вечера. У меня такой вопрос. Если в ячейках таблицы хранится текст который содержит двойные и одиночные кавычки ("", '') То при выполнения запроса к базе данных с использованием переменной содержащей эти символы запрос будет нарушен... Вот пример:

```
$i = "NEELL"OM";
$results = $db->query('SELECT time FROM bd WHERE name = "$i"');
```

как видите в переменной i имеется ", и запрос выполнен не будет... Подскажите как решить эту проблему. Буду премного благодарен.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно выполнить *экранирование*: каждую кавычку внутри текста необходимо удвоить.

```
$i = 'Test string""';
$results = $db->query('SELECT time FROM bd WHERE name = "'.$i.'"');
```

В PHP есть специальная функция: [sqlite_escape_string](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.sqlite-escape-string.php). Совсем по-хорошему будет пользоваться методами [prepare](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/sqlite3.prepare.php) и [bindValue](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/sqlite3stmt.bindvalue.php).

В разных БД и языках программирования способ экранирования может различаться (в большинстве случаев это экранирование спомощью обратного слеша), но называется везде одинаково - экранирование / escaping.

Comment: Но у меня нету возможности добавлять кавычки в переменную i потому что её значения берутся из другой таблицы.. И количество таких переменных велико. Может быть есть какой нибудь иной способ? Или быть может можно при формировании запроса удвоить кавычки?
>$results = $db->query('SELECT time FROM bd WHERE name = ""$i""');
Или что нибудь подобное? Чтобы исключить возможность ошибки?

Comment: Нашёл информацию, по экранированию.. http://ru2.php.net/manual/ru/sqlite3.escapestring.php  Но не совсем понял, как оно работает.. Не могли бы подсказать?

Comment: @istimbi, пока у вас между двумя вызовами работает PHP - есть. Можно просто заменить все кавычки на двойные в строке:

    $i = str_replace('"', '""', $i);

Comment: Спасибо. Сейчас попробую.

Comment: @istimbi, по-хорошему это все должно делаться не руками, но я с SQLite не работал, поэтому не могу показать на нужные функции (escapeString по идее должен был бы делать то, что нужно, но кавычки почему-то не удваивает). Совсем по-хорошему использовать вышеуказанные prepare/bindValue - там механизм экранирования должен быть встроен сам по себе.